# Pergunta sobre herança

Tags: java

Eu estou tentando criar um programa que calcula a área de um retângulo e de um triângulo. Para isso eu criei uma classe Forma com os atributos base e altura, uma subclasse Retangulo com o atributo areaRetangulo, uma subclasse Triangulo com o atributo areaTriangulo e uma classe Main com o código principal, mas quando eu rodo o programa e insiro os valores, o valor da área dá 0.0.

Classe Forma:

```
package pacote;

public class Forma {    
    double base;
    double altura;
        
    }
```

Classe Retangulo:

```
package pacote;

public class Retangulo extends Forma {
    double areaRetangulo = base * altura;
    
    
}
```

Classe Triangulo:

```
package pacote;

public class Triangulo extends Forma {
    double areaTriangulo = base * altura / 2;
    
}
```

Classe Main:

```
package pacote;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        
        Retangulo retangulo = new Retangulo();
        
        Triangulo triangulo = new Triangulo();
     
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Nosso sistema calcula as áreas de um triângulo e de um retângulo");
        
        System.out.println("Digite a base do retângulo: ");
        retangulo.base = scan.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Digite a altura do retângulo: ");
        retangulo.altura = scan.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Digite a base do triângulo: ");
        triangulo.base = scan.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Digite a altura do triângulo: ");
        triangulo.base = scan.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Área do retângulo = " + retangulo.areaRetangulo);
        System.out.println("Área do triângulo = " + triangulo.areaTriangulo);
        
    
}
}
```

Comment: tentou debugar pra ver se os valores das variáveis foram armazenados?

Comment: Não deveria ser ‘triângulo.altura’ em alguma chamada?

Comment: O último Scan está sendo armazenado em ```triangulo.base``` em vez de ```triangulo.altura```.

Comment: pois é @CésarRodriguez, eu disse isso no meu comentário. Que está logo acima do seu.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve transformar o código abaixo

```
double areaTriangulo = base * altura / 2;
```

em um método.

Explico: quando você cria o objeto Triângulo e Retângulo, você automaticamente cria as variáveis de 'area'. Mas nesse momento, a 'base' e 'altura' não tem um valor definido, então a área fica zerada. Quando você lê valores para base e altura, você de fato atribui os valores, mas na sequência você só pede para mostrar na tela a área de cada objeto, que não foi alterada, pois ela teve um valor atribuído só quando você criou os objetos.

A solução seria algo assim:

```java
    // retangulo
    public double calculaArea() {
        return base * altura;
    }
    
    // triangulo
    public double calculaArea() {
        return (base * altura)/2;
    }
```

Coloque esses métodos nas classes Retangulo e Triangulo, e remova a atribuição na variável 'areaRetangulo' e 'areaTriangulo'.

No final do programa, você deve chamar retangulo.calculaArea() e triangulo.calculaArea().